# Godot raycast colliding too high

Tags: collision-detection, raycasting, godot

I am making an fps that uses a raycast for shooting. I used some suggestions taken from a few reddit pages, but it's mostly my own code. It was working properly, until I noticed that when you shot up above the enemy, it still registered as a hit. Does anyone know why this might be happening? code:

```
func use_weapon():
Raycast.force_raycast_update()
if Raycast.is_colliding():
    var collider = Raycast.get_collider()
    if collider:
        if collider.has_method("takedamage"):
            collider.takedamage(10)
```

Comment: Can you show us how you aim your ray?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kywX5wH

Comment: Can you enable collisions under Debug>Visible Collision Shapes? You will see the ray and how it is hitting the enemy. Maybe the ray just points in the wrong direction, or the hitbox of the enemy is too large.

Comment: Found the problem. For some reason, the ray moved left and right, but not up and down. I'll look in to what caused this, but in the meantime, write an answer so I can mark it as correct.